# How dict objects are pickled?

Tags: python, pickle

After reading pickle documentation, I got an impression that a class needs to implement either `__reduce__` or `__getstate__` to get pickled correctly. But how pickling of dictionaries work then? They don't have any of those attributes:

```
> dict(a=1).__reduce__()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/daniyar/work/Apr24/<ipython-input-30-bc1cbd43305b> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(a=1).__reduce__()

/usr/lib/python2.6/copy_reg.pyc in _reduce_ex(self, proto)
     68     else:
     69         if base is self.__class__:
---> 70             raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
     71         state = base(self)
     72     args = (self.__class__, base, state)

TypeError: can't pickle dict objects



> dict(a=1).__getstate__()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/daniyar/work/Apr24/<ipython-input-31-00932fb40067> in <module>()
----> 1 dict(a=1).__getstate__()

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '__getstate__'
```

Also, how classes derived from dict are pickled?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The pickle module handles a number of types "natively"](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). The types it *doesn't* handle natively will need to implement the ["pickle protocol"](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol).  Dicts, and simple subclasses, are handled natively.

Answer (score 4):

The `__reduce__` and `__getstate__` methods are meant to be the lower bound of pickling methods, for you to implement on your custom classes when it needs some special treatment from the interpreter.

For example, if an instance of an extension class is inside a dictionary you are trying to pickle, that renders the whole dictionary unpickable if your class doesn't implement those methods saying how to pickle it.

The interpreter knows how to pickle builtins, and to pickle a dictionary you should use `pickle.dump` or `pickle.dumps` method, not by calling `__reduce__` or `__getstate__`.

Answer (score 3):

Pickling does not require either `__reduce__` or `__getstate__`.  Those are methods that you can use to control pickling, but pickle will work on built-in types without them just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The useful answer I got from [here](http://western-skies.blogspot.com/2008/02/simple-complete-example-of-python.html)

Here is what is supposed to be inside `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`. Even though somehow you can't use it right away as it supposed to, but you can make it from scratch, like this:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    result = self.__dict__.copy()
    return result

def __setstate__(self, dict):
    self.__dict__ = dict
```

Answer (score 1):

All good answers, but they ignore the question:

> Also, how classes derived from dict are pickled?

They are pickled by reference, like any other class.
If you look at the pickle, you can see what python is doing.

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "MyDict({})".format(dict(i for i in self.items()))
... 
>>> m = MyDict(a=1,b=2)
>>> m
MyDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2})
>>> import pickle
>>> # reconstructor called on class MyDict that lives in __main__
>>> # and contains a __builtin__ dict with contents ('a' and 'b')
>>> pickle.dumps(m)
"ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\nMyDict\np1\nc__builtin__\ndict\np2\n(dp3\nS'a'\np4\nI1\nsS'b'\np5\nI2\nstp6\nRp7\n."
>>> m.clear()
>>> # removing the contents, to show how that affects the pickle
>>> pickle.dumps(m)
'ccopy_reg\n_reconstructor\np0\n(c__main__\nMyDict\np1\nc__builtin__\ndict\np2\n(dp3\ntp4\nRp5\n.'
>>> # now, just looking at the class itself, you can see it's by reference
>>> pickle.dumps(MyDict)
'c__main__\nMyDict\np0\n.'
```

Or, we could do the same, but inspect the disassembled pickles. You can see exactly what instructions are stored.

```
>>> pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps(m))
    0: c    GLOBAL     'copy_reg _reconstructor'
   25: p    PUT        0
   28: (    MARK
   29: c        GLOBAL     '__main__ MyDict'
   46: p        PUT        1
   49: c        GLOBAL     '__builtin__ dict'
   67: p        PUT        2
   70: (        MARK
   71: d            DICT       (MARK at 70)
   72: p        PUT        3
   75: t        TUPLE      (MARK at 28)
   76: p    PUT        4
   79: R    REDUCE
   80: p    PUT        5
   83: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 0
>>> pickletools.dis(pickle.dumps(MyDict))
    0: c    GLOBAL     '__main__ MyDict'
   17: p    PUT        0
   20: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 0
```

The class is definitely stored by reference, even thought it derives from a `dict` instead of `object`. The reference is to the name, which means that once the `__main__` session is closed, the class definition would be lost and the pickle that depends on `MyClass` won't load.

Now, let's look at the `dict`.  A `dict` pickles by first relying on python knowing how to serialize fundamental objects like the `dict` (as mentioned in other answers), then it goes about serializing the contents.  You can see it has two `strings` in it, which python also inherently knows how to serialize.

This means if you have unserializable objects in the dict, it will fail.

```
>>> d['c'] = MyDict.__repr__
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'c': <unbound method MyDict.__repr__>, 'b': 2}
>>> pickle.dumps(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle instance method objects
```

We *can* do better, btw, if you use a better serializer. Using `dill` instead of `pickle` enables most objects to be serialized. The pickle of the dict is much more complicated, as you can see below.

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dumps(d)
'\x80\x02}q\x00(U\x01aq\x01K\x01U\x01cq\x02cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x03U\nMethodTypeq\x04\x85q\x05Rq\x06cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x07(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x08T$\x01\x00\x00c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s#\x00\x00\x00d\x01\x00j\x00\x00t\x01\x00d\x02\x00\x84\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x02\x00\x83\x00\x00D\x83\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00S(\x03\x00\x00\x00Ns\n\x00\x00\x00MyDict({})c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00s\x15\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00]\x0b\x00}\x01\x00|\x01\x00V\x01q\x03\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x02\x00\x00\x00.0t\x01\x00\x00\x00i(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>s\t\x00\x00\x00<genexpr>\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00(\x03\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00formatt\x04\x00\x00\x00dictt\x05\x00\x00\x00items(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00__repr__\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\t\x85q\nRq\x0bc__builtin__\n__main__\nU\x08__repr__q\x0cNN}q\rtq\x0eRq\x0fNcdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x10(h\x03U\x08TypeTypeq\x11\x85q\x12Rq\x13U\x06MyDictq\x14h\x03U\x08DictTypeq\x15\x85q\x16Rq\x17\x85q\x18}q\x19(U\n__module__q\x1aU\x08__main__q\x1bh\x0ch\x0fU\x07__doc__q\x1cNutq\x1dRq\x1e\x87q\x1fRq U\x01bq!K\x02u.'
>>> pickletools.dis(dill.dumps(d))
    0: \x80 PROTO      2
    2: }    EMPTY_DICT
    3: q    BINPUT     0
    5: (    MARK
    6: U        SHORT_BINSTRING 'a'
    9: q        BINPUT     1
   11: K        BININT1    1
   13: U        SHORT_BINSTRING 'c'
   16: q        BINPUT     2
   18: c        GLOBAL     'dill.dill _load_type'
   40: q        BINPUT     3
   42: U        SHORT_BINSTRING 'MethodType'
   54: q        BINPUT     4
   56: \x85     TUPLE1
   57: q        BINPUT     5
   59: R        REDUCE
   60: q        BINPUT     6
   62: c        GLOBAL     'dill.dill _create_function'
   90: q        BINPUT     7
   92: (        MARK
   93: c            GLOBAL     'dill.dill _unmarshal'
  115: q            BINPUT     8
  117: T            BINSTRING  'c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s#\x00\x00\x00d\x01\x00j\x00\x00t\x01\x00d\x02\x00\x84\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x02\x00\x83\x00\x00D\x83\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00S(\x03\x00\x00\x00Ns\n\x00\x00\x00MyDict({})c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00s\x15\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00]\x0b\x00}\x01\x00|\x01\x00V\x01q\x03\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x02\x00\x00\x00.0t\x01\x00\x00\x00i(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>s\t\x00\x00\x00<genexpr>\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00(\x03\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00formatt\x04\x00\x00\x00dictt\x05\x00\x00\x00items(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00__repr__\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01'
  414: q            BINPUT     9
  416: \x85         TUPLE1
  417: q            BINPUT     10
  419: R            REDUCE
  420: q            BINPUT     11
  422: c            GLOBAL     '__builtin__ __main__'
  444: U            SHORT_BINSTRING '__repr__'
  454: q            BINPUT     12
  456: N            NONE
  457: N            NONE
  458: }            EMPTY_DICT
  459: q            BINPUT     13
  461: t            TUPLE      (MARK at 92)
  462: q        BINPUT     14
  464: R        REDUCE
  465: q        BINPUT     15
  467: N        NONE
  468: c        GLOBAL     'dill.dill _create_type'
  492: q        BINPUT     16
  494: (        MARK
  495: h            BINGET     3
  497: U            SHORT_BINSTRING 'TypeType'
  507: q            BINPUT     17
  509: \x85         TUPLE1
  510: q            BINPUT     18
  512: R            REDUCE
  513: q            BINPUT     19
  515: U            SHORT_BINSTRING 'MyDict'
  523: q            BINPUT     20
  525: h            BINGET     3
  527: U            SHORT_BINSTRING 'DictType'
  537: q            BINPUT     21
  539: \x85         TUPLE1
  540: q            BINPUT     22
  542: R            REDUCE
  543: q            BINPUT     23
  545: \x85         TUPLE1
  546: q            BINPUT     24
  548: }            EMPTY_DICT
  549: q            BINPUT     25
  551: (            MARK
  552: U                SHORT_BINSTRING '__module__'
  564: q                BINPUT     26
  566: U                SHORT_BINSTRING '__main__'
  576: q                BINPUT     27
  578: h                BINGET     12
  580: h                BINGET     15
  582: U                SHORT_BINSTRING '__doc__'
  591: q                BINPUT     28
  593: N                NONE
  594: u                SETITEMS   (MARK at 551)
  595: t            TUPLE      (MARK at 494)
  596: q        BINPUT     29
  598: R        REDUCE
  599: q        BINPUT     30
  601: \x87     TUPLE3
  602: q        BINPUT     31
  604: R        REDUCE
  605: q        BINPUT     32
  607: U        SHORT_BINSTRING 'b'
  610: q        BINPUT     33
  612: K        BININT1    2
  614: u        SETITEMS   (MARK at 5)
  615: .    STOP
highest protocol among opcodes = 2
```

`Dill` serializes the class method because there's additional functions that have been registered to `dill` that know how to pickle and unpickle a wider variety of objects -- you can see them in the disassembled code (they start with `dill.dill`).  It's a much bigger pickle, but it generally works for any contents you stuff into a `dict`.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> everything = dill.dumps(globals())
```

For classes deriving from `dict`, you don't have to worry about having unpicklable objects inside of the class methods -- however, the *contents* of the custom `dict` are still serialized with the class instance, so you do have to worry about having unserializable objects contained within your class.

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 11 2014, 01:21:43) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.1 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import pickle
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...   def __repr__(self):
...     return "MyDict({})".format(dict(i for i in self.items()))
... 
>>> m = MyDict(a = lambda x:x)
>>> m
MyDict({'a': <function <lambda> at 0x10892b230>})
>>> pickle.dumps(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>> pickle.dumps(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1374, in dumps
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 401, in save_reduce
    save(args)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 663, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 748, in save_global
    (obj, module, name))
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function <lambda> at 0x10892b230>: it's not found as __main__.<lambda>
```

A `lambda` fails to serialize because it doesn't have a name that `pickle` can refer to.  Going back to `dill`, we see this works, however.

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.dumps(m)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_type\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_load_type\nq\x01U\x08TypeTypeq\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04U\x06MyDictq\x05h\x01U\x08DictTypeq\x06\x85q\x07Rq\x08\x85q\t}q\n(U\r__slotnames__q\x0b]q\x0cU\n__module__q\rU\x08__main__q\x0eU\x08__repr__q\x0fcdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x10(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x11T$\x01\x00\x00c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s#\x00\x00\x00d\x01\x00j\x00\x00t\x01\x00d\x02\x00\x84\x00\x00|\x00\x00j\x02\x00\x83\x00\x00D\x83\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00S(\x03\x00\x00\x00Ns\n\x00\x00\x00MyDict({})c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00s\x15\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00]\x0b\x00}\x01\x00|\x01\x00V\x01q\x03\x00d\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x02\x00\x00\x00.0t\x01\x00\x00\x00i(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>s\t\x00\x00\x00<genexpr>\x03\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00(\x03\x00\x00\x00t\x06\x00\x00\x00formatt\x04\x00\x00\x00dictt\x05\x00\x00\x00items(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x04\x00\x00\x00self(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00__repr__\x02\x00\x00\x00s\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01q\x12\x85q\x13Rq\x14c__builtin__\n__main__\nh\x0fNN}q\x15tq\x16Rq\x17U\x07__doc__q\x18Nutq\x19Rq\x1a)\x81q\x1bU\x01aq\x1ch\x10(h\x11U\\c\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00C\x00\x00\x00s\x04\x00\x00\x00|\x00\x00S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x01\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00x(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x07\x00\x00\x00<stdin>t\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x1d\x85q\x1eRq\x1fc__builtin__\n__main__\nU\x08<lambda>q NN}q!tq"Rq#s}q$b.'
```